# How to setup a notification for all error events of Backup and FileHistory-Core in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, backup, file-history

I had (in the past) multiple issues with the old Windows 7 Image Backup & Restore (0x8078015B, 0x8078014B, 0x80070015, etc.) and the Windows 10 Filehistory ([Event 201 szett-bug](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/special-char-eszett-bug-in-windows-file-history/2f8bd33e-47cc-48df-b14b-f4f1cb8481d9?auth=1), Event 204  full backup drive, etc.). My mums Windows PC failed creating backups for weeks because of a similar problem.

I'm annoyed about that because Windows never informed me about these failing backups. As a stopgap solution I attach to every new error in the event viewer a task and start the application "msg" with the command "* XYZ failed with event 123" ([METHOD 1: Using Command Prompt](http://www.askvg.com/fix-cant-create-tasks-to-display-messages-in-windows-8-task-scheduler/)).

But because of this unreliability I like to have notifications for all error events of those services. Is this possible or do you suggest a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you looking for a script to monitor the events logs and display a message?

Comment: @RandySchuman I like to have notifications for all backup related errors. If a script solves my problem this could be a solution.

Comment: I have a script I posted here that could be modded for that purpose.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242077/wql-statement-to-check-an-applications-event-log/39284068#39284068  I Just need to know if I should pull from "System" or "Application". It already has logging. Do you want to display a message on the screen also? It should be setup as a scheduled task instead of running continuously.